# Add data to Json after fetch in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I have an api client that works fine getting the info from a Json in a website. What I want is to add some new rows to that bundle of content after fetching from the website.

I read about the **.push** function, but don't know where to put in the new ES6 format and can't fine any info in Google.

I'm using:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0
```

This is the code:

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/data.json';

customData = [
  {
    autor: 'Mike',
    category: 'category name',
  }
]

function getJsonData() {
  return fetch(BASE_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.items.item)
    .then(myData => myData.push(customData)) // <- Trying to add custom data
    .then(news => news.map(item => {
      return {
        autor: item.author,
        category: item.category,
      }
    })
  )
  //.then(news => news.push(customData)) // <- Also I tried here
}

export { getJsonData }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `data.items.item` is not returning a Promise you can use with `then`.

Use async/await to save you trouble:

```
async function getJsonData() {
    const response = await fetch(BASE_URL);
    const json = await response.json();

    // Not clear what you're trying to accomplish here but should give
    // you an idea
    data.items.push(customData);
    return json.items.map((item) => {
       return {
         autor: item.author,
         category: item.category,
       }
    });
}
```